# error apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe"

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost

Last time I try add new domain on localhost and I leave it on few weeks so now I try run my apache this command `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` and I get error

```
[....] Starting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

If i tried to do reinstall apache2 but it is still not work.

Comment: seems like same question as http://serverfault.com/questions/717825/apache2-service-not-restarting-rails-ubuntu/755539#755539

Comment: Stop nginx, if is running.

Answer (score 8):

I just did these two lines.**It worked.**

*Two web servers cannot be active on the one port at the same time*

this code for **apache** & **nginx**:

or

if error **journalctl -xe** used this code

```
sudo apt-get install psmisc
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:80 -s tcp:listen | sudo xargs kill
```

Answer (score 7):

### Virtual Host configuration might cause this error

I solved this same problem by configuring my virtual host .conf files properly.

I created a virtual host & then removed the exapmle.conf file form **/etc/apache2/sites-avalable/** but I didn't deleted the examle.conf file from **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/** for this reason i was getting this error.

Then I removed the example.conf file from both the folders( **../sites-enabled & ../sites-available )** and solved this issue.

If you tried to setup any virtual host recently, then try this solution.

Best of Luck

Answer (score 7):

**Kill the running process on the port**. Hope it will work!

```
sudo apt-get install psmisc
sudo fuser 80/tcp
sudo lsof -i tcp:80
sudo lsof -i tcp:80 -s tcp:listen
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:80 -s tcp:listen | sudo xargs kill
```

Comment: I just did these two lines :     sudo apt-get install psmisc      sudo lsof -t -i tcp:80 -s tcp:listen | sudo xargs kill

Comment: Save my whole Day Thanks you so much !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Go

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

remove this line:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then

```
service apache2 start/restart
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem may be a result of some configuration files in apache missing. One of the solutions would be to purge the apache2 file.
You can type:

sudo apt-get purge apache2

Then reinstall apache2 by typing:

sudo apt-get install apache2

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message, we just have to execute :

```
systemctl status apache2.service
```

or

```
journalctl -xe
```

And you will have more detail about the error (line of the error, or command misspelled, or module not included in the configuration, ...) :
for example you can have following detail Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration ==> you then need to execute a2enmod ssl, and then execute service apache2 restart

Also I notice a difference between service apache2 reload and service apache2 restart commands. In case of persisting errors you should execute service apache2 restart, and then execute journalctl -xe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because some configuration files are deleted.

You can use the following command to replace configuration files that have been deleted, without purging the package:

```
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

You type

```
sudo netstat -pant
```

You check are you using port 80. If used, `

```
sudo service 'service_name' stop
```

and

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Answer (score 0):

execute **sudo service apache2 status** and check the result. it might be trying to bind to a port that is already in use